# Setting read / write / execute privilege on "cgi-bin" folder in Windows Azure webrole

Tags: azure

We're talking about a simple webapp.

So I have a file called "modulev2.cgi" which is part of a trusted 3rd party online payment company. This file has to be put in a folder named "cgi-bin". For windows IIS environnement the file is renamed "modulev2.exe" and put in the same directory. This is what the documentation says.
Module is called as this :
    FORM ACTION=../cgi-bin/modulev2.exe METHOD=post

with a bunch of parameters. It should not download when called of course but execute.

And indeed it does work in my dedicated server, provided the "cgi-bin" folder and the file in have "execute" setting level in IIS.

So to the point, would I be able to set the rights to execute to this file in Windows Azure ? If yes, how to script such a process ?

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to script it out locally against your IIS using appcmd.exe.  You want to add your CGI handler programmatically.  By default, IIS in Windows Azure is already running CGI/Fast-CGI, so you don't have to install it, it should be ready.  I think you need to add it to the CGI restriction list and add your handler mappings.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732851(WS.10).aspx

Once you have a .cmd file that will correctly configure your local IIS settings, you can use that as the basis for a Startup task in Windows Azure to bootstrap the role.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-31-Startup-Tasks-Elevated-Privileges-and-Classic-ASP

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-34-Advanced-Startup-Tasks-and-Video-Encoding

Comment: Hello, so there is a way to do it. I'm going to dig into this appcmd thing. Thanks a lot for your help !